# Does the Sage X3 ERP have a REST API?

Tags: sage-erp

Does the Sage X3 ERP have a REST API that I can

- create a new purchase order with
- download a list of all existing customers in the ERP?

This seems like a very basic question about their product, but neither a Google search nor the [official documentation at](https://developer.sage.com/x3/)  answers it. The official docs say X3 has:

- a GraphQL API
- a SOAP API, that looks incomplete, that is, only covering a small part of the functionality of Sage
- APIs for file-based integration or import/export